# Hard IQ questions with arrows

Tags: sequence

I have been looking at it for hours without a solution[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Hi there, and welcome to Puzzling :) Please can you tell us where you found this particular IQ question? All questions posted from elsewhere need some attribution, so we can make sure the original content creator is appropriately credited. A link to the website is usually sufficient. Thanks!

Comment: It’s an interview question haha I donno where they get it from

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> The first one. The arrow that starts at the top moves clockwise by one-quarter of a circle in each successive box; the one that starts at the bottom moves counterclockwise by one-eighth of a circle in each successive box.